# How do i sum net amount based on policy and based on instno in below XML by using XQUERY

Tags: xml, xquery

How do i sum net amount based on policy and based on instno in below XML by using XQUERY.

```
XML:
    <root>
        <StatementDetail>  
                <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>
        <name>john</name>
                <InstallmentNo>0</InstallmentNo>  
                <NetAmount>250.00</NetAmount>              
        </StatementDetail>
        <StatementDetail>  
                <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>
        <name>john</name>  
        <InstallmentNo>1</InstallmentNo>  
                <NetAmount>50.00</NetAmount>              
        </StatementDetail>
        <StatementDetail>  
                <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>
        <name>ravi</name>  
        <InstallmentNo>0</InstallmentNo>  
                <NetAmount>270.00</NetAmount>              
        </StatementDetail>  
        <StatementDetail>  
                <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>
        <name>ravi</name>
        <InstallmentNo>0</InstallmentNo>    
                <NetAmount>230.00</NetAmount>              
        </StatementDetail>
        </root>
        };
    
here is code for based on policy :
    
    {
      for $x in ./root/StatementDetail
      let $PolicyNo := fn:upper-case($x/PolicyNo)
      group by $PolicyNo
      order by $PolicyNo
      return <statement>
            <StatementDetail>{$PolicyNo}</StatementDetail>
            <NetAmountSum>{sum($x/NetAmount)}</NetAmountSum>
          </statement>
    }
```

Output should be like this:

```
Policy      Name    InstNo  Amount

POL-01      John    0       250
                    Total   250
                    1        50
                    tOTAL   50
Total POL-01                300
POL-02      Ravi   0       270
                    0       230
                    tOTAL   500
Total POL-02                500
```

I want to do sum of net amount based on policy and based on instno in below XML by using XQUERY.
As i want to display other fields too so  when i use group by clause in xquesry i have to take others
fileds in groupby and my grouping fails.
Please guid me writting Xquery for that.

Comment: Rumesh, please provide two things: (1) your XQuery software and its version, and (2) Desired output format: XML or something else.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky its a Dev Studion company has its own software and in that we have Docgen tool where we write xquery. as i saw ur previous comment on the same issues its work but now i have something tricky.